# How to pass a list of AZs from Terraform to a CloudFormation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cloudformation

I have a CloudFormation template that defines this parameter:

```
        "AvailabilityZones" : {
            "Description" : "List of Availability Zones used ... ",
            "Type" : "List<AWS::EC2::AvailabilityZone::Name>"
        },
```

I invoke the CF template like this:

```
resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "xxx" {

  name = "xxx-stack"

  template_body = file("../cloudformation/xxx_CloudFormation_template_2.1.1.json")

  parameters = {
    VpcId                = aws_vpc.xxxvpc.id
    SubnetCidrBlock      = var.aws_vpc_cidr 
    AvailabilityZones    = var.aws_azs
    InstanceType         = "m5.4xlarge"
    ExternalNet          = "0.0.0.0/0"
    ....
  }

  on_failure = "DELETE"
}
```

Where:

```
variable "aws_azs" {
  default = ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b", "us-east-1c"]
}
```

I get the error:

```
Inappropriate value for attribute "parameters": element "AvailabilityZones": string required.
```

I have tried many variations on this theme, but I can't see how to pass a list of AZs to the CF template from TF.

I am also more than a little puzzled by the assertion that a string is required in the error message, as the parameter type in the CF template is defined as a list.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to use the `templatefile` function instead of the `file` you are using in the `template_body` field. You can pass variables there and fill the template with passed variables with nice template engine. You can use variables, functions, statements and loops there.

Example is here https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/templatefile.html

Your example

```
resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "xxx" {

  ....

  template_body = templatefile("../cloudformation/xxx_CloudFormation_template_2.1.1.json", {
 aws_azs = var. aws_azs
})

  ....
}
```

and your cf file:

```
 "AvailabilityZones" : {
            "Description" : "List of Availability Zones used ${join(',', aws_azs)} ",
            "Type" : "List<AWS::EC2::AvailabilityZone::Name>"
        },
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand the idea. It has has the downside that I have to edit the CF template, which comes from a third party. Ideally I would be able to achieve what I need without editing the CF template itself.

Answer (score 1):

To pass a list of values from Terraform to CloudFormation you will need to join them as a comma separated list.

**TL;DR**

```
resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "this" {
  ...
  parameters = {
    AvailabilityZones = join(",", ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b", "us-east-1c"])
  }

}
```

**Explanation**

To pass lists of things to a CloudFormation template you will have to either pass a native construct or a comma separated list of values.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/multiple-values-list-parameter-cli/

Consider we have a CloudFormation template `cfn-template.yml` that requires us to pass a list of AZs as parameter:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Parameters:
  AvailabilityZones:
    Description: List of Availability Zones used ...
    Type: "List<AWS::EC2::AvailabilityZone::Name>"
Resources:
  NullResource: # CF needs at least 1 resource, so we hand it a dummy
    Type: "AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle"
Outputs:
  PassedAvailabilityZones:
    Description: The AZs passed into the cfn template from Terraform.
    Value: !Join [ ",", !Ref AvailabilityZones ]
```

In your terraform we will need to create a comma separated string of these values and pass them in the parameter block.

```
variable "aws_azs" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b", "us-east-1c"]
}

resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "this" {
  name = "test-pass-azs"

  parameters = {
    AvailabilityZones = join(",", var.aws_azs)
  }

  template_body = file("./cfn-template.yml")
}

terraform {
  required_version = "~> 1.0"

  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.0"
    }
  }
}
```